# Get array of tuples from txt file

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tuples

I've txt file with content:

```
("All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.","Walt Disney")
("The secret of getting ahead is getting started","Mark Twain")
```

I want to get array of tuples from it with type [(String, String)]. I try to use code:

```
do {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quotes", ofType: "txt"){
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
        let arrayOfStrings = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        print(arrayOfStrings[0])
    }
} catch let err as NSError {
    // do something with Error
    print(err)
}
```

But with it I cannot get tuple values. How I can get array of tuples from txt file with Swift?

Comment: Why do you have `(` in your text? Is that normal? It looks like almost as it it was CSV, but not quite. Like if you wanted to write directly "tuples". Do you have the possibility to change the initial text?

Comment: Yes. I can change.

Comment: Look for JSON, XML/Plist then? That's common and "easy" formats to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments by Larme it would be better to properly format your text. If you can't change the text format you woill need to manually parse its contents:

```
let data = """
("All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.","Walt Disney")
("The secret of getting ahead is getting started","Mark Twain")
"""

let tuples = data.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
    .compactMap { line -> (Substring,Substring)? in
        let comps = line.components(separatedBy: #"",""#)
        guard comps.count == 2,
              let lhs = comps.first?.dropFirst(2),
              let rhs = comps.last?.dropLast(2) else { return nil }
        return (lhs,rhs)
    }

for tuple in tuples {
    print(tuple.0)
    print(tuple.1)
}
```

---

This will print:

> All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.
> Walt Disney
> The secret of getting ahead is getting started
> Mark Twain

Comment: But if I can change the format of text, what will be better solution to parse it?

Comment: use a json string